Closed-form of the hypergeometric function?
Is there a closed-form of the following generalized hypergeometric?
$${}_3F_2\left(\left.\begin{array}{c}1,1,\frac13\\\frac54,\frac74\end{array}\right|1\right) ;\quad{}_3F_2\left(\left.\begin{array}{c}1,1,\frac23\\\frac54,\frac74\end{array}\right|1\right) $$

I will omit the “$\bigg|1$” in the description of the problem later on.

The source of the problem is that I was working with another hypergeometric function ${}_5F_4\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac13,\frac23,\frac14,\frac34,\frac{10}{9}\\[1mm]1,\frac43,\frac53,\frac19\end{array}\right) $, which I transformed into a sum of three hypergeometric functions (From wolframalpha).
$${}_5F_4\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac13,\frac23,\frac14,\frac34,\frac{10}{9}\\[1mm]1,\frac43,\frac53,\frac19\end{array}\right)= 2\,{}_3F_2\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac13,\frac14,\frac34\\[1mm]1,\frac43\end{array}\right)-{}_3F_2\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac23,\frac14,\frac34\\[1mm]1,\frac53\end{array}\right)+\frac{27}{160}\,{}_4F_3\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac43,\frac53,\frac54,\frac74\\[1mm]2,\frac73,\frac83\end{array}\right)$$
Then I tried to find the value of each hypergeometric function separately. I used Thomae’s Theorem to transform two of the hypergeometric functions into the form in the question that
$${}_3F_2\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac13,\frac14,\frac34\\[1mm]1,\frac43\end{array}\right)=\frac{\sqrt2\pi}{16} {}_3F_2\left(\begin{array}{c}1,1,\frac23\\[1mm]\frac54,\frac74\end{array}\right);\quad {}_3F_2\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac23,\frac14,\frac34\\[1mm]1,\frac53\end{array}\right)=\frac{\sqrt2\pi}{8} {}_3F_2\left(\begin{array}{c}1,1,\frac13\\[1mm]\frac54,\frac74\end{array}\right)$$
So is it possible to find the closed form of the two hypergeometric functions given in the title? If not, is it possible to find the closed form of the difference ${}_3F_2\left(\begin{array}{c}1,1,\frac13\\\frac54,\frac74\end{array}\right) -{}_3F_2\left(\begin{array}{c}1,1,\frac23\\\frac54,\frac74\end{array}\right) $?
Or just prove that $${}_5F_4\left(\begin{array}{c}\frac13,\frac23,\frac14,\frac34,\frac{10}{9}\\[1mm]1,\frac43,\frac53,\frac19\end{array}\right)=4-\frac{24}{\pi}\arcsin\left(\frac13\right).$$
If there is no closed form for the hypergeometric function in the question, then I think it's possible that there are transformation formulas between ${}_3F_2$ and ${}_4F_3$ that can make a lot of parts cancel out of the sum of those three hypergeometric functions, but I'm not aware of the existence of such a transformation formula.
